# Configuring IIS (v7.5) for ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-7.5, application-pool

If I have IIS 7.5 or newer, and I want to make sure my ASP.NET application hosted on IIS is as responsive and available as possible, one thing I do is usually setting the `Start Automatically` advanced setting for the app pool in IIS to `true`:

[image]

My question that I'm scratching my head about (and can't seem to find a definitive answer for) is: if the `Start Automatically = true` is set, does the `Idle Time-out (minutes)` setting have any effect?

As far as I understand, the `Start Automatically` setting makes sure the app pool is always up and running and available - so doesn't that kinda "kill off" the concept of an "idle timeout" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start automatically as the description reveals, only enables the application pool upon creation or when IIS restarts. It has nothing to do with the other setting.